# Solving VirusTotal Detections

Tags: c#, antivirus

I've made some simple tools for use in the modding scene for a game (mechwarrior 5) however the programs are getting flagged by VirusTotal. Is there anything I can do to reduce the detections?
I'm not interested in getting a certificate.

Detections:

- https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/54718ac0e161e00930ac32ec8cde04d98aacb37ba786d57cc15aac61b0eba7dd/detection
- https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/cb7602a956118db4697e481ffc5d02fe08d96b5de9676d7ad882c3331044057a/detection

Source code for given files:

- https://github.com/rjtwins/MW5-Mod-Manager
- https://github.com/rjtwins/MW5LOMLauncher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting cerificate could significantly reduce number of false positives, however you say that's not an option for you. Other than that I can advise:

1. report false positives to AV companies. It usually helps but not always possible to find the way to report it and then to get any answer
2. use something like bisection method. Simplify app and check if it still fails. If fails/passes - check more simple/complex app trying to find what breaks detection and then trying to re-implement that breaking change in some other way.

Comment: I was afraid it was gonna have to be done the hard way :(